# NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier returning null for other application

Tags: macos

I was trying to use NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier in my application to visit apple mail bundle, bundleIdentifier is "com.apple.mail", it returnned null for the other application bundle identifier, why it will not get the bundles of the not running application, like:
[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.mail"];

Comment: What bundle you are trying to get access to? `bundleWithIdentifier:` is tend to work with internal bundles that are part of a bundle of running application (such as frameworks, resource bundles, helpers etc.) You can't access bundles of others applications because of SandBox. You can try to put some bundles into Documents, and gain access to them by  `bundleWithPath:` or `bundleWithURL:`

Comment: For example, We have applications A and B, A could launch B via RPC, in A, I want to get bundles of B which contain version information, so I use [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"bundleIdentifierOfB"]; but got a null bundle, what should I do for this case?

Comment: I wonder how do you use RPC internally. Typically, you would use X-Callbacks, see http://x-callback-url.com/ (which already seems to be anticipated by Apple themself, see https://support.apple.com/de-de/guide/shortcuts/use-x-callback-url-apdcd7f20a6f/ios )

Comment: @assult If we are talking about iOS, there is no way A can access anything from B  because of sandbox https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html

Comment: @MichaelV How about Mac, do we have any way to do this on Mac?

Comment: On Mac you had to use bundle `bundleWithURL:` or `bundleWithPath:`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, but with the Python pyObjC bridge. I found a workaround using the AppKit framework there, but my fix will be directly translatable to your issue. C.f. [pyObjC Foundation NSBundle.bundleWithIdentifier_ will not look up application. NSBundle.bundleWithPath_ will](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74354569/pyobjc-foundation-nsbundle-bundlewithidentifier-will-not-look-up-application-n)

And the pyObjC intro docs which you can use to translate between Python and Objective C: https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/intro.html

I'm not an Objective C developer, so I'm gonna **try** to write it in objective, but basically, you need to get the path of your app, using the bundle identifier using `[ NSWorkspace URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier:]`  then do whatever you need using `[NSBundle bundleWithUrl:]`

Why this is, I don't know. Good luck.