# How can I locate an NSBundle knowing its bundle-Identifier? (e.g. "com.apple.Preview")

Tags: objective-c, macos, bundle

I need to extract the **executable path** for apps (and other bundles) whose bundle-identifier I know, but not their installed location.

For some reason, the [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:] method fails for just any identifier I use. Either mine, Apple's or 3rd party.

```
NSBundle *appBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.Preview"];
if (appBundle)
   NSLog(@"Bundle executable: %@", appBundle.executablePath);
else
   NSLog(@"No bundle for identifier: %@", identifier); 
    
appBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath: @"/System/Applications/Preview.app"];
if (appBundle)
   NSLog(@"Bundle executable: %@", appBundle.executablePath);
else
   NSLog(@"No bundle for path: %@", path);
```

Output looks like:

```
2022-11-28 16:51:19.04 TesterApp[2802:96004] No bundle for identifier: com.apple.Preview
2022-11-28 16:51:40.88 TesterApp[2802:96004] Bundle executable path: /System/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview
```

I tried everything. Running as root, giving "full disk access" permissions to my TesterApp executable before running. Running from the same directory (/Applications) where Apple Preview.app resides - to no avail.

Just can't make `bundleWithIdentifier:` work.

To add insult to injury - there are two contradicting lines in [the method documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1411929-bundlewithidentifier)

> **Return Value**
>
> The NSBundle object with the bundle identifier identifier, or nil if
> the requested bundle is not found on the system.
>
> This method creates and returns a new NSBundle object if there is no
> existing bundle associated with identifier. Otherwise, the existing
> instance is returned.

Now can anyone explain - what SHOULD the method return when a bundle with given identifier cannot be found on the system?

is it `nil`, or a new bundle object?

I saw a few related questions, but none actually trying to locate a bundle on the hard drive - by its bundle-id.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier returning null for other application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52825358/nsbundle-bundlewithidentifier-returning-null-for-other-application)

Comment: `[NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Preview"];`

Comment: Found this already, but it only works for Apps (not even all Apps). It won't locate Framework bundles, Plugin bundles, System-Extension bundles or any other executable bundle other than Apps. Its predecessor in LaunchServices - LSCopyApplicationURLsForBundleIdentifier() does exactly the same. I specifically want to understand why NSBundle API won't work despite documentation, Maybe I'm missing some permissions? capabilities?

Comment: @Willeke This is not a duplicate, as that question referred only to Apps, while I'm looking for Bundles in general - Including Frameworks, Plugins System-Extensions etc. Also - take note that no real answer was provided on that question too.

Comment: Have you tried without app sandbox?

Comment: The two lines in the documentation aren't contradicting. "This method creates and returns a new NSBundle object if there is no existing bundle associated with identifier. Otherwise, the existing instance is returned." means "if you call this method twice you get the same instance, not another one". If a bundle with given identifier cannot be found on the system then `nil` is returned.

Comment: That documentation does seem to be a bit of a mess - apparently most of those just work for app bundles (tested without sandbox).  You might try Spotlight, e.g. `mdfind "kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier == com.apple.filesystems.apfs"` and go from there.

Comment: Cool idea, except I'm running very close to the kernel (EndpointSecurity Client) and I can't run any external NSTasks/Processes, and must also meet VERY tight deadlines. I must find a programmatic API for that. Why not suggest this as an Answer to the question, so it'll benefit other users?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make any difference. It's not a sandboxing issue - it is a Cocoa documentation issue. I now understand better what it DOES DO, alas the documentation doesn't tell you that. Hints are available in the oldest CFBundle documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The [NSBundle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle) documentation isn't very clear, as the `bundleWithIdentifier` method has a couple of paragraphs that list three results (existing bundle, new object, or nil) for only two possibilities (bundle is there or not).  That method appears to only work within an application, and returns nil if the bundle identifier is not found.

Testing with a non-sandboxed app, `LSCopyApplicationURLsForBundleIdentifier` and NSWorkspace’s `URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier` work for apps, but at least that can be inferred from the name.  Using NSBundle’s `bundleWithPath` would seem to defeat the purpose, since you would already have the path.

Searching the Spotlight metadata for a matching `kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier` does seem to work, however.  The `mdfind` shell utility or [NSMetadataQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmetadataquery) work with bundle identifiers from apps, kexts, components, and most script bundles I've tried, although it does depend on the particular locations being indexed (and the bundle having an **Info.plist**).  A path from the result could then be used to manually build the executable path at **/Contents/MacOS/**.

Comment: Thanks, this is mostly what I managed to do till now - except for the NSMetadataQuery I did not know exists. So your answer IS a new lead here... I'll be trying with it. If it provides a path - I can initialize an NSBundle from that path - and ask it about the executable.  I'm mainly interested in bundles containing executables (either Apps, plugins, XPC-Services, System-Extensions, Frameworks and such).

Comment: Actually the meaning "is there or not" is a riddle by its own right. I thought they meant "is there such a package in your file system" - and in reality it means: "is there an NSBundle object already loaded and cached in memory". Knowing that- the rest of the documentation makes (kind of...) sense. The hint I got was reading the documentation of CFBundle. It's older and much better, and although incomplete, it at least tells what it does.